# Receiving "blocked by CORS policy" error when invoking HERE Map from locahost

Tags: cors

I am trying to include a HERE Map into my Angular8 application. After following the get-started tutorial and adding my public IP to the "Domain Whitelist", the map does not load properly and spews out several 'blocked by CORS policy" errors:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://signature.venue.maps.api.here.com/venues/signature/v1?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id={this-is-my-app-id}&app_code={this-is-my-appcode}' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This is the tutorial that I followed:
https://developer.here.com/blog/display-here-maps-angular-web-application

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -3):

Since you are using locahost to do tests. You can use this [web extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en).

But take note that in production level use, your domain name must be added to the endpoint that your are requesting to have the initiator app access to the content.

Comment: Hi Edcel, thanks for your input. 

I managed to resolve my issue by following a different tutorial on the HERE Developer portal:  https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.14.0/dev_guide/topics/get-started.html. 

I suspect the code in the previous tutorial I used might have been outdated. Following this tutorial the code works fine!

Regards
Morné